# Abort/Cancel http post request with angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, post, abort

I have been trying to find a way to cancel/abort http post request with $q.defer on angularjs, but it seems that it doesn't work. I have set a simple demonstration and you can take a look at the example here:

`Demo program:`http://plnkr.co/edit/gkvxRj/

This issue with it is that:
1. If I use get method, if I click the "Send Request" button quickly, it will cancel previous request and start a new request, so there will be only one request gets processed successfully. 
2. If I changed to post method, If I click the "Send Request" button quickly, it won't cancel previous post request and start new request. That is to say, there will be a bunch of post requests get processed, which is not what we need.

So my question is that am I doing anything wrong or is there a way to cancel/abort post request with angularjs?

Comment: Maybe you should use angular's http interceptors. Have you consider that? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2777-monitoring-http-activity-with-http-interceptors-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Thanks Robson, I am new to angularjs and will give it a try.

Comment: From the plnkr it seems even get doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, it is not working because the ajax endpoints is on my local. I didn't find a ajax request which accepts post request.